# How to make two columns from one list

Tags: wiki

I have one list and I want to make two columns from him, something like this:

I have this:

```
 ====== Known Errors ======

1. 
2.    
3.
.....
47.
```

and I want this

```
====== Known Errors ======

1.                              28.
2.                              29.  
3.                              30. 
....                             ....
27.                              47.
```

and my code is this :

```
====== Known Errors ======
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/table_not_accessible|Control table not acessible]]                    
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view|Calendar view used by multiple users]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/Unknown_Publisher|Unknown Publisher]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/error_during_update|Error during the update of TLP to a new version/SP]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view/doc_new_version|Create new version of a document]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/export_ms_proj|Export to MS Project]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/save_filter_in_resource|Save filter in Resource planning]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/new_order|Create new order]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/open_test_report|Open test report]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup|Application startup]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup_tlp|Application 'TLP.exe' startup ]]
  - [[testlabplus/known_errors/proj_code_on_order|Project code on an order]]


FIXME
```

Answer (score 1):

Wiki documentation offers use directive `columns_list`.
In your case:

```
====== Known Errors ======
    {{columns_list|2|
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/table_not_accessible|Control table not acessible]]                    
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view|Calendar view used by multiple users]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/Unknown_Publisher|Unknown Publisher]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/error_during_update|Error during the update of TLP to a new version/SP]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view/doc_new_version|Create new version of a document]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/export_ms_proj|Export to MS Project]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/save_filter_in_resource|Save filter in Resource planning]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/new_order|Create new order]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/open_test_report|Open test report]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup|Application startup]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup_tlp|Application 'TLP.exe' startup ]]
      - [[testlabplus/known_errors/proj_code_on_order|Project code on an order]]
    }}
```

**For external links**:

```
{{columns_list|2|
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/table_not_accessible Control table not acessible]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view Calendar view used by multiple users]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/Unknown_Publisher Unknown Publisher]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/error_during_update Error during the update of TLP to a new version/SP]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/calendar_view/doc_new_version Create new version of a document]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/export_ms_proj Export to MS Project]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/save_filter_in_resource Save filter in Resource planning]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/new_order Create new order]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/open_test_report Open test report]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup Application startup]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/app_startup_tlp Application 'TLP.exe' startup ]
  - [//testlabplus/known_errors/proj_code_on_order Project code on an order]
}}
```

Comment: I don't know why, when I used this form  appear all this rows and they are red

Comment: 'testlabplus/known_errors/table_not_accessible' and other is external link?

Comment: If your links is external then you need to wrap each link somesing like this `- [//testlabplus/known_errors/table_not_accessible Control table not acessible]`

Comment: I put that link after I created the page

Comment: the code is good because work, but my question is how to make two columns

Comment: and if you know : how can put more spaces like this : daniela       ____________________________                                        pop ?